# Enabling Spring Security global method security breaks dependency injection (with Kotlin)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, kotlin

I am currently working on the authentication system for a Spring Boot application, and I've been having issues since I tried to enable Spring Security's global method security.

The Spring Boot application being a REST API, the authentication system is a bit non-standard, so I have set up a custom authentication filter that I add to the `HttpSecurity` object that pre-processes the request, calls a custom `AuthenticationManager` and gives the final `Authentication` object to the `SecurityContextHolder`. And that works fine!

However, with this method, I have to set up all the access rules for my endpoints directly in my overridden `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure` method, which I find less-than-practical, so I tried to use Spring Security `@PreAuthorize` annotation directly in my controllers instead.

The problem is, if I add `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` to my security configuration, all the `@Autowired` attributes in my controllers are not injected. It works fine if I set `prePostEnabled = false` or if I remove the annotation altogether, but of course this isn't what I want.

Here a stacktrace that shows the request handler being called (and the attributes not being initialized):

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property accountService has not been initialized
        at com.example.api.module.account.AccountController.addAccountRole(AccountController.kt:105) ~[main/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at com.example.api.security.HeaderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(HeaderAuthenticationFilter.kt:46) ~[main/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at com.example.api.security.HeaderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(HeaderAuthenticationFilter.kt:46) ~[main/:na]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

And here's some of my classes which I think are relevant with all their annotations to illustrate my explanation.

com/example/api/security/SecurityConfig.kt :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) // works if absent
open class WebSecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var authFilter: HeaderAuthenticationFilter

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.addFilterAt(authFilter,
                AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter::class.java)
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/accounts").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        http.csrf().disable()
    }
}
```

com/example/api/module/account/AccountController.kt :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/accounts")
open class AccountController {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var accountService: AccountService

    // [...]

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN') or hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1')")
    @RequestMapping(method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST),
            value = "/{id}/roles")
    fun addAccountRole(@RequestBody data: PostAccountRoleData,
                       @PathVariable("id") id: Long):
            ResponseWrapper {
        val account = accountService.findAccount(id) // line 105, exception here
        accountService.updateAccount(account.copy(authority = data.roles))
        return ResponseWrapper(StatusMessage.SUCCESS)
    }
}
```

com/example/api/module/account/AccountService.kt :

```
interface AccountService {
    fun getAllAccounts(): List<Account>
    fun findAccount(id: Long): Account

    // [...]
}
```

com/example/api/module/account/DatastoreAccountService.kt :

```
@Service("accountService")
class DatastoreAccountService : AccountService {
    // [...] implementation details
}
```

So how could I resolve this? I know that activating global method security activates some kind of proxy but I have no idea why and how it could affect dependency injection on my controllers.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's my build.gradle file, too:

```
group 'com.example.api'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.1'
    ext.spring_boot_version = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    ext.spring_security_version = '4.2.2.RELEASE'
    ext.jackson_kotlin_version = '2.9.0.pr2'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$spring_boot_version"
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com'
    }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:$spring_security_version"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:$spring_security_version"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:$jackson_kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-datastore:+'
}

jar {
    baseName = 'example-api'
    version = "$version"
}

appengine {
    deploy {
        stopPreviousVersion = true
        promote = true
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

// Set-up the datastore emulator environment variable for debugging
bootRun {
    environment "DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST", "localhost:8081"
    environment "DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID", "example-api"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I managed to fix it.

I think that the issue was that while my `AccountController` was declared as `open`, some of my Kotlin classes weren't (for those unfamiliar with Kotlin, that mean that those classes were declared as `final` in the JVM), and it was messing with dependency injection somehow (maybe some CGLIB weirdness?). I didn't think the problem would come from here, because usually Spring throws an exception when it fails to inject a dependency for such reasons, but it didn't in this case. It may or may not be normal, but I don't have enough knowledge about Spring internals to be able to say that the lack of exception thrown is a bug.

Anyway, back to our issue. One way to fix it (I think) without adding any more dependencies would be to go through your entire code and mark Spring-annotated classes (and maybe subclasses too) as `open` for them to drop their `final`-ness.

However, JetBrains released a compiler plugin called `kotlin-allopen` to automatically declare classes with specific annotations as `open`, and you can even use `kotlin-spring` to automatically configure it with Spring annotations!

So the other, simpler way to fix it would be to add this to your build.gradle (there is a maven version, too):

```
// Add to dependencies
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"

// [...]

apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use kapt in your gradle file for moxy compiler.

Most stable configuration is kapt with generate stubs is given in the following example

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.redmadrobot.moxysamplekotlin"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile project(':moxy')
    compile project(':moxy-android')
    kapt project(':moxy-compiler')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

For full details, please check this github issue: [lateinit property Presenter has not been initialized](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/issues/41)

Comment: Thank for your answer! I'm a bit confused though, as I'm not using moxy which is, from what I've read, a library for Android development? Or maybe do I need to use kapt on one of my dependencies? I've added my build.gradle file to my post above, if it can help.